# What's a good strategy to get the Flower Power achievement?

Tags: achievements, plants-vs-zombies

I'm playing *Plants vs. Zombies* on the iPhone and one of the achievements is "Flower Power: Keep 10 Twin Sunflowers Alive in a Single Level". I've tried on many different levels — standard, water, fog, rooftop — but the level doesn't seem to last long enough for me to even plant 10, let alone keep them alive. The cooldown for twin sunflowers is just too long! So what am I missing? What's a good way to get this achievement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key is that speed of zombie spawning is somewhat controlled by how fast you kill them, so try to make it as slow as possible.  Potato mines are great early on.  Snow peas are also good at doing slow damage.  And of course you can just throw up walls for them to slowly eat through.  Buy yourself enough time and you should have no problem getting enough sunflowers going.

Answer (score 1):

- try it in Survival Mode.
- <strike>alternate between the twin sun flower and the Imitater.</strike>
- stall the zombies with columns of tall nuts and little offense.

Comment: I thought the imitater could not be used to duplicate Twin Sunflowers?

Comment: @JavadocMD - It's been a while, but it's dawning on my now. Yup, it can't do upgrades.

Answer (score 0):

You can try it on survival endless where the zombies keep coming forever so you will have enough time. However, make sure your defenses are strong enough or the zombies will overwhelm you.